# Hive lateral view with sample example with hive table having 2 columns as array

Tags: hive

I have a row with data in the format:

```
Col1    col2     col3
1       (1,2,3)  (A,B,C)
```

I want the output in the format:

```
col1  col2  col3
==== ====== =====
1      1    A
1      2    B
1      3    C
```

I am not able to use explode to get data in this format

Comment: mention the dataypes of the source table, especially col2 and col3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

**Register a Hive UDF**

Locate the `hive-contrib-<version>.jar` for your distribution, and add it in Hive so that it is available to all nodes. The below path is from a Hortonworks HDP distribution.

```
hive (default)> add jar /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-contrib-1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37.jar;
```

Register the `row_sequence()` UDF.

```
hive (default)> create temporary function row_sequence as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence';
```

**Execute query**

```
SELECT e.col1 col1, f.col2 col2, f.col3 col3 
FROM
hive_tbl e,
(
    SELECT c.col2, d.col3 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT row_sequence() entryseq, a.col2 
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT EXPLODE(col2) col2
            FROM hive_tbl
        ) a
    ) c 
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT row_sequence() entryseq, b.col3 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT EXPLODE(col3) col3
            FROM hive_tbl
        ) b
    ) d
ON 
c.entryseq = d.entryseq
) f;
```

**Illustration:**

**Data file**

```
-- testarray.txt
1|1,2,3|A,B,C
```

**Load file to HDFS**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /hive-data/array
hadoop fs -put testarray.txt /hive-data/array
```

**Create and verify Hive Table**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `default.hive_tbl`(
  col1 string,
  col2 array<string>,
  col3 array<string>
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
collection items terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
LOCATION 'hdfs:////hive-data/array';

select * from hive_tbl;
hive_tbl.col1   hive_tbl.col2   hive_tbl.col3
1               ["1","2","3"]   ["A","B","C"]
```

**Execute the query**

```
-- query output
col1    col2    col3
1       1       A
1       2       B
1       3       C
```